# gradle android: post-process APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to post-process my APK by adding a second signature, so I'm trying to understand how to hook into the build process at that point. my first attempt,

```
task doubleSign {
  if (signing.androidBuildExists) {
    android.buildTypes.all { type ->
      tasks.("assemble${type.name.capitalize()}").finalizedBy doDoubleSign
    }
  }
}
```

okay fine. but if any of the `install*` tasks are executed, then much to my surprise, `assemble*` isn't in the dependency tree. so next i tried adding the line,

```
tasks.("install${type.name.capitalize()}").dependsOn doDoubleSign
```

however, gradle tells me that task doesn't exist!

```
> Could not find property 'installDebug' on task set.
```

Comment: Android does not honor a second signature. What do you expect to gain by this?

Comment: we are doing our own validation on the APK. we have a custom firmware that requires the app to be signed by the dev and our "app store".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`installDebug` won't be present when that code is executed because the android plugin creates its tasks in the `afterEvaluate` phase.

What you should do:

```
android {
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (!variant.isSigningReady()) {
      // only add double signing on variants that are signed with
      // default signing method.
      return
    }

    // get output file
    def outputFile = variant.outputFile

    // add new signing task.
    def signingTask = project.tasks.create("double${variant.name}Sign", MyCustomSigning)
    // configure task
    signingTask.inputFile = outputFile
    // create the final apk name using baseName to guarantee it's unique.
    signingTask.outputFile = new File(project.buildDir, "apks/${project.name}-${variant.baseName}-2sign.apk")

    // configure the task to be run after the default signing task.
    signingTask.dependsOn variant.packageApplication

    // configure zip align task to use the output of the 2nd signing task,
    // and also to run after 2nd signing task.
    variant.zipAlign.inputFile = signingTask.outputFile
    variant.zipAlign.dependsOn signingTask
  }
}
```

Note that if you don't run zipalign (but really you should) you'll have to tweak the end to make `variant.assemble` depend on your signing task instead and to set the output of your signing task to `variant.outputFile` so that deployment from command line or IDE still works.

For the actual signing you would do a custom task with the annotations so that it only runs if the input file actually change.

```
class MyCustomSigning extends DefaultTask {
  @InputFile
  File inputFile

  @OutputFile
  File outputFile

  @TaskAction
  void sign() {
    // call script to sign inputFile into outputFile
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, but i am lost on how to hook in the actual signing. i have a script that will add a second signature, then re-zipalign. i want to hook that in after the final APK is assembled. yeah, if it could be done all in gradle, that'd be great.

Comment: It's better to let Gradle zipalign and focus on the signing only. I added an example of a custom task.

Comment: thanks again for the tips. after some pain i arrived at a solution. i'll post it in my answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question has been answered, I want to share the solution that worked best for me.

All I needed was a suitable hook to post-process a completely finished apk. For this I used the hook "assemble.doLast":

```
android {
    /* ... */

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                File apk = output.outputFile
                // Post process apk
            }
        }
    }
}
```